# Add a Dropdown dynamically on button click and bind values using knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I Have to add a dropdown dynamically on a button click. I'm trying to update the array but it is not showing the values in dropdown

```
<a data-bind='click:addBillItem'>Add</a>
```

My View Model is given below:

```
function AssignmentViewModel() {
self.billDescriptions = ko.observableArray();

this.addBillItem = function() {
            var = '<select id="ddlBillItemDescription" data-bind="';
            html += 'options:billDescriptions,';
            html += 'optionsText:"ItemName",';
            html += 'optionsCaption: "Select Bill Description",';
            html += 'optionsValue:"ItemName",';
            html += 'value:BillItemDescription';
            html += '</select>';
            $("#dropdown").append(html);
            self.billDescriptions(billItemDescriptions);
var billItemDescriptions = GetBillItemDescriptions();
self.billDescriptions(billItemDescriptions);
        };
}
ko.applyBindings(new AssignmentViewModel());
```

Comment: @Origineil I already have a ddlBillItemDescription dropdown on page load and bindings are applied to it. I want to bind the data to the dropdown that i added on button click

Comment: Applying bindings is how you bind data. If the html is not present in the DOM when you do so, you haven't bound it. See [example](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/gh9goz7L/)

Comment: @Origineil Thanks, tried with your example but i'm getting an error like  "You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element."

Comment: As is expected, if you click it more than once. Describe (in an edit to your post) what it is you are trying to achieve to clarify why you are approaching the problem this way. Either way, direct `jQuery` DOM manipulation is not the ideal "knockout" way, you can usually achieve a desired behavior strictly through a combination of bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 options that I would recommend:

1) If you only need one of these dropdowns, put it in the markup with an `if` binding. Then, all you need to do is flip the flag bound to `if` to make your dropdown appear.

2) If you're going to make multiple dropdowns, setup a `foreach` binding in the markup, with the dropdown in the template (use the `options` binding). Then, in the viewmodel, have an array of objects representing the individual dropdowns (these are what will be bound to the `options` binding.

Comment: Exactly the approach I was [putting together](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/wevsqmkr/), but had to go to a meeting :).